# Why i get this error, where i made error?

Tags: cakephp

I tried register script for cake from [here](http://pastebin.com/3XteNTCS) and i get this error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\premke\xampps\xampp-win32-1.7.3\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 23

Where i made error. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You will need to show your setup, including the ominous register.php so that someone can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you have taken something out of the cakephp context - the normal cake or app folder - and installed it in the root folder of your webserver.
Without being processed by cake this is meaningless. I would suggest you start again from a vanilla cake installation and edit the files in place (in fact, it occurs to me that you manipulated the default.ctp and created php-file from that).